# Mutual SSL client certificate validation(Key Usage and Extended Key Usage) in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, openssl

I have configured a tomcat connector for handling requests for a particular servlet and have configured a trust store for the connector. Anyone knows whether tomcat handles validation of "Key Usage" and "Extended Key Usage" extensions in client certificates? And how it's handled through tomcat(is it through the tomcat connector)?